# Application defined error for range formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very simple sub to input some formulas into a range. For some reason I get an "Application-defined or object-defined error". Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code. I have done this before and it worked fine.

```
Sub ResetONE()
   Range("I7:AA27").Formula = "=IFERROR($F7/IF(OR(I$6<$C$5,I$6=""""),"""",DATEDIF($D$1,$D$5,""m"")-DATEDIF($D$1,$C$5,""m"")+1,"""")"
End Sub
```

Comment: Missing a parenthesis after the `+1`.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you, sir.